# Multiple details section in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, reporting

Below is my sample report. `COL` stands for column and `VAL` for values. Now the report contains one details section.

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4   COL5

VAL1 VAL2 VAL3 VAL4.1 VAL5.1
VAL1 VAL2 VAL3 VAL4.2 VAL5.1
VAL1 VAL2 VAL3 VAL4.3 VAL5.1
VAL1 VAL2 VAL3 VAL4.1 VAL5.2
VAL1 VAL2 VAL3 VAL4.2 VAL5.2
VAL1 VAL2 VAL3 VAL4.3 VAL5.2
```

I want the report to be like this.

```
Details a COL1 COL2 COL3
          Val1 Val2 Val3
Details b COL4    COL5
          Val4.1  Val5.1
          Val4.2  Val5.2
          Val4.3
```

Could you please help me in this ?

Comment: Not clear, please edit to set data in a tabular format as it right now flows

Comment: @NitinSingh : Please check for the revised version.

Comment: Thank you @MatSnow for the edit